# items between the hr tag in HTML. Top HR tag is not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have a hr tag at the top and then my company logo and name of the company and an HR tag at the bottom. I wrote the below code to achieve this, but it is not showing the way I want it. Below is my code and the image:

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-top"><hr class="new5" /></div>
    <div class="ss-header-title">
     <div class="d-flex align-items-top px-5 mb-3">
                        
                        <img src="images/download.jpeg" class="logo mr-3" />
      <h4>Test Company Name</h4>
      
     </div>
    </div>
                 <div><hr class="new5" /></div>
                 

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
           
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
```

Below is the image:

[image]

My above HR looks like a dot. I want the top HR totally at the top. Below is the css for new5:

```
.new5 {
    border: 5px solid green;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

The bottom HR tag is fine, but the top one is not all the way to the top and it is showing as a dot

any help will be appreciated.

Code with Border top and border bottom:

```
            <div class="d-flex align-items-top px-5 mb-3">
                 <%--<img src="images/county-logo.png" class="logo mr-3"  />--%>
                <img src="images/download.jpeg" class="logo mr-3" />
                <h4>Test Company Name</h4>

            </div>

            <div><h1 class="border-bottom"></h1></div>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
```

The top border is not all the way to the top. I want something like orange top border in stack overflow web site

I tried your code, it looks like this.

[image]

I want the logo in between two HR and top hr should be totally at the top

below is the image that I am getting with your code:

[image]

[image]
              
              The Angry Vulture

©  - My ASP.NET Application

Comment: Why don't you do a border-top and border-bottom?

Comment: I am not aware of that. I will try right now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this code a try and let me know how it goes on your end. The logos and name I used it to see the final look and feel, sorry about that!
Please make sure you add the Bootstrap css library in the head section as I have it on the code I am sharing with you. I certainly hope this helps!

```css
.new5 {
        border-top: 5px solid green !important;
        border-radius: 2px;
        width:100%;
}
    
 .logo {
 display:block;
 height: 45px;
 width:45px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
          <title>HR issue</title>
          <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="container">
              <div class="border-top mb-1 border-bottom border-success py-2 new5">
                <div class="ss-header-title">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
                      <a href="#">
                      <img src="https://www.theregister.co.uk/media/834.gif" alt="" class="logo" >
                      </a>
                      <h4 class="my-1 mx-2 text-info">The Angry Vulture</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
              <footer>
              <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
              </footer>
          </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I want the logo in between two HR and top hr should be totally at the top. The angry vulture logo should be in between the two HR and the top HR should be totally at the top just like the orange border in stackoverflow web site

Comment: Version has been updated. Please have a look at a different approach see if this aims towards your expected resolution.

Comment: I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I am not getting what you are getting. Please see the picture above.

Comment: I also want the company name right next to the logo not under the logo